# Is there an easy way to compute Euclidean distance matrix in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scipy

Is there an efficient way to compute the Euclidean distance matrix in TensorFlow, given either the Gram matrix or the coordinates?

The Euclidean distance matrix is an n-by-n matrix whose entries are given by the squared distance between each pair of points (x,y,z). The Gram matrix is simply the matrix of inner products. So if X is a 3-by-n matrix whose columns are the points, then the Gram matrix is given by X^T@X. There is a simple formula to convert from the Gram matrix to the distance squared matrix.

In other words, is there an easy way to write the following numpy/scipy functions in TensorFlow (v1 in particular)? If so, which one would be more efficient?

```
# Compute Euclidean distance matrix from Gram matrix
def euclidean_dist_from_gram(gram):
    temp = np.tile(np.diag(gram), (nodes,1))
    return temp + temp.T - 2*gram
```

```
# Compute Euclidean distance matrix from coordinates
def euclidean_dist_from_pts(xyz):
    return spt.distance.squareform(spt.distance.pdist(xyz.T, 'sqeuclidean'))
```

EDIT: The above two functions can be run in numpy and scipy by first importing the following dependency and generating random data:

```
import scipy.spatial as spt
xyz = np.random.uniform(-20, 20, (3,500))
gram = xyz.T@xyz
```

Comment: Can you add examples for both the cases using generated data?

Comment: Added what I think you wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, so I figured I'd post an answer to my own question. It's easiest to compute the Euclidean distance matrix from the Gram matrix, so here's the TensorFlow implementation (assuming a 3 x n coordinates matrix xyz). The thing I didn't realize is that I had to use tf.expand_dims in order to use tf.tile, and then it matches the numpy implementation.

```
gram = tf.linalg.matmul(tf.transpose(xyz), xyz)
g = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.linalg.diag_part(gram), 0), tf.constant([n,1]))
euclidean_dist = g + tf.transpose(g) - 2*gram
```